# Obtener fecha y hora de una base de datos MySQLpara utilizar en aplicación VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, base-de-datos, vba, aplicación-escritorio

Actualmente tengo instalada una aplicación que diseñe en distintos computadores que se conecta a una base de datos que tengo en otra maquina.

Dentro de la aplicación realizo cálculos de tiempo que necesito para mostrar ciertos datos. Actualmente lo que hago es obtener la fecha actual haciendo uso de `System.DateTime`, sin embargo pienso que esto eventualmente puede dar problemas ya que según entiendo con `System.DateTime` tomo la hora del equipo donde esta instalada la aplicación.

Debido a que los computadores en donde esta la aplicación no tienen exactamente la misma hora, quería saber si hay alguna forma de obtener la fecha y hora directamente de la maquina donde esta la base de datos para que de esta manera la aplicación siempre busque la hora en esta maquina y no en la maquina donde esta instalada la aplicación. Las maquinas están conectadas mediante una red LAN y **NO TIENEN ACCESO A INTERNET** por lo que obtener la fecha y hora de la Internet no es una opción.

Agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan brindar, Gracias :).

Comment: Hay varias formas de obtener esa información, usando NTP,WMI,el comando NET TIME...echa un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008111/get-the-exact-time-for-a-remote-server)

Comment: La primera opción que sería más fácil es utilizar la función `NOW` de MySQL para todas esas funciones donde compruebas la hora para que así tome en cuenta la del servidor de BD en lugar de donde se ejecuta la aplicación. Aquí te dejo [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now). La segunda opción es que tomes el DateTime en tu sistema y lo "traslades" a la hora universal UTC con [ToUniversalTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) y, al mismo tiempo, establ

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugiero realizar el [tour] para entender mejor el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tenga buenas respuestas, saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Ya lo revise lo tendre en cuenta para futuras preguntas :)

Comment: @N.Agudelo te agradezco, de esta forma podrías obtener mejores respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera sencilla es con el comando `NET TIME` usando `Process` y parseando la salida redirigida del comando. Esta es una posible implementación:

```
string servidor = "nombreDeTuServidor";

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = @"time \\" + servidor;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();

//leemos la salida del comando
string procResult= proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

DateTime serverDateTime;

//Comprobamos que el comando ha devuelto la hora correctamente
if (procResult!=null && procResult.Contains("correctamente"))
{
    //Obtenemos la cadena con la fecha
    string date = procResult.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' }).Where(x => x.Contains('/')).FirstOrDefault();
    //Obtenemos la cadena con la hora
    string time = procResult.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n' }).Where(x => x.Contains(':')).FirstOrDefault();
    //Finalmente obtenemos un objeto DateTime con la fecha y hora del servidor
    serverDateTime = DateTime.Parse(string.Join(" ", date, time));
}
```